# Gui for debugging comparing large collections of Java objects in parallel files. 

Tags: java, debugging, javabeans, debuggervisualizer

I have some large, binary files with serialized data in them.  I would like to create a "generic" ObjectGUI that allows me , for example to .

1) Select several files

2) Select a "reader" or "handler" class

3) Open each file in columns

4) View the Objects in those columns (i.e. query the fields, sort, etc).

So basically, I want a Navicat style interface to some binary files.  Just for context, these files are thrift serialized hadoop files, but a generic interface capable of reading objects from any source (i.e. hibernate, or an ObjectOutputStream, etc...) would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

This is decidedly nontrivial.

I would approach it as follows

1. Create domain specific class wrapping the data you are trying to read
2. Create the unmarshaller which parses the binary protocol and creates objects from step 1

Once you have the objects, visualizing them is another matter.  If they adhere to JavaBeans conventions (get/set), you might be able to use [NetBeans property inspector](http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-property-editors.html) to drill down into the various properties.  I've used this API before; it's slightly tricky.

If you instead want to go for a grid/table based approach, I'd advise you use [GlazedLists](http://www.glazedlists.com/).  You will need to implement a class which converts your domain objects into columns in a table - read the [tutorial](http://www.glazedlists.com/documentation/tutorial) for more details

Please don't focus too much on having this generically support every thing ever - or you might fall into this trap.  Just focus on getting it to work with the cases you have.

[image] (http://xkcd.com/974/)